# Alu with clock and reset

Tags: vhdl

I have a project to create an ALU with clock and reset signals, but for the following code this error appears "Illegal sequential statement". I think the problem is instantiating entities inside a process. How can i fix this?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity alu is
    port(a: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
         b: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
         c: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
         opcode: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
         rst: in std_logic;      
         cout: out std_logic;
         output: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
         zero: out std_logic);
end alu;

architecture my_arch of alu is

    component mux4to1_32bits
    port (and_in: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          not_in: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
              or_in: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          xor_in: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          sel: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
              f: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
    end component;

    component mux2to1_32bits 
    port (in1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          in2: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          sel: in std_logic;
          output: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
    end component;

    component full_adder_32bits
    port (in_a: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          in_b: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          cin: in std_logic;
          fa: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          cout: out std_logic);
    end component;

    component and_32bits
    port (in1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          in2: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          output: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
    end component;

    component or_32bits
    port (in1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          in2: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          output: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
    end component;

    component not_32bits
    port (in1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          output: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
    end component;

    component xor_32bits
    port (in1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          in2: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          output: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
    end component;

    component zero_flag
    port ( result: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
           zf: out std_logic);
    end component;

    signal port_and: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal port_or: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal port_not: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal port_xor: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

    signal port_not1: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal output_mux2to1: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal output_mux4to1: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal output_fa: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal mid_output: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

    signal Clk : std_logic := '0';
    constant Clk_period : time := 10 ns;

begin
    Clk_process :process
    begin
            Clk <= '0';
            wait for Clk_period/2;
            Clk <= '1';
            wait for Clk_period/2;
    end process;

    stim_proc: process
    begin     
        wait for Clk_period*2;
        and_port: and_32bits port map (a(31 downto 0),b(31 downto 0),port_and(31 downto 0));
        not_port: not_32bits port map (a(31 downto 0),port_not(31 downto 0));
        or_port:  or_32bits port map (a(31 downto 0),b(31 downto 0),port_or(31 downto 0));
        xor_port: xor_32bits port map (a(31 downto 0),b(31 downto 0),port_xor(31 downto 0));
        not1_port: not_32bits port map (b(31 downto 0),port_not1(31 downto 0));

        mux2to1_1: mux2to1_32bits port map (b(31 downto 0),port_not1(31 downto 0),opcode(0),output_mux2to1(31 downto 0));
        mux4to1: mux4to1_32bits port map (port_and(31 downto 0),port_not(31 downto 0),port_or(31 downto 0),port_xor(31 downto 0),opcode(1 downto 0),output_mux4to1(31 downto 0));
        fulladder: full_adder_32bits port map (a(31 downto 0),output_mux2to1(31 downto 0),opcode(0),output_fa(31 downto 0),cout);
        mux2to1_2: mux2to1_32bits port map (output_fa(31 downto 0),output_mux4to1(31 downto 0),opcode(2),mid_output(31 downto 0));
        zero_output: zero_flag port map (mid_output(31 downto 0),zero);

        output <= mid_output;
        wait;

    end process;
end my_arch;
```

Comment: Process = sequential statements. Components = concurrent statements. How did you learn VHDL without coming across the differences between sequential and concurrent statements?

Comment: "A process statement defines an independent sequential process representing the behavior of some portion of the design.... process_statement_part ::= { sequential_statement }" (IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.3).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. You should instantiate your component's port maps outside the `stim_proc`.  Think of or visualize this as *next to*, or *along side* your processes. It is just the *wiring* of signals between components and process circuits. Within the process you would have only the code that describes how the data moves *across* the signals that run between your processes and components.

Comment: "A net is a collection of drivers, signals (including ports and implicit signals), conversion functions, and resolution functions that, taken together, determine the effective and driving values of every signal on the net." IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.3, your *wiring*. "Concurrent statements are used to define interconnected blocks and processes that jointly describe the overall behavior or structure of a design." (11.1). "A component instantiation statement defines a subcomponent of the design entity in which it appears,..." (11.7.1). A process statement is the bottom level of a design hierarchy.